# Get part of a dynamic url

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get a part of the URL on my website

In this situation:

```
http://mywebsite/filexx/yyyyy/abaete/374    

$url2 = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if(preg_match("/\/(\d+)$/",$url2,$matches))
{
    $meuid = $matches[1];
}
```

its works, but lets put 2 different situations:

```
http://mywebsite/filexx/yyyyy/abaete/374/?p=1
// i'm try to get the 374 (ID)

http://mywebsite/filexx/yyyyy/374/?p=1
// here the same
```

so I want to get last part if integer ( 374 )
or the part before the query 374/?p=1. So I want the 374.

Thanks.

Comment: `.*?/(\d+)` ? :) (it will also ignore the `/?getval1=1&getval2=2&etc=etc`)

Comment: Can you generalize the rules you're using to match?  Is it always a number in that position?

Comment: Also, is it always 3 digits or more? you can change your regex to look for 3+ digits instead of just 1+

Comment: Hi @Daedalus i have 2 situations the last position will be ever the id like website/xxx/1 or website/xxx/1/?p=1  where p is my pagination so i want to try 1 function i can get the number 1 (ID) on both situations.

Comment: Hi @Syndrose no there can be 1, 2, 3.... the number is the ID.

Comment: I'm wondering if `filexx, yyyyy, abaete, 374` are folders, otherwise i would think you're rewriting urls which means that those variables get stored somewhere in your script, which means that this is useless ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just make my comment an answer:

```
<?php
    $string = 'http://mywebsite/filexx/yyyyy/abaete/374/?g=123';
    $matches = array();

    preg_match_all('/.*?\/(\d+)\/?/s', $string, $matches);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

It will also ignore the /?getval1=1&getval2=2&etc=etc

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://mywebsite/filexx/yyyyy/abaete/374/
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 374
        )

)
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. The normal regex won't work in PHP as you need to escape the slashes.

Comment: Yes works, the $matches[1][0] will be always the ID i need. Thanks dude.

Comment: Never rely fully on it tho. Always check the array for it's structure. Glad I could help :) Good luck!

Comment: Try this `$string = 'http://mywebsite/filexx/yyyyy/abaete/374/?g=123&url=http://otherwebsite.com/news/234';` as test and see you get two values back. Be sure to test it with some weird cases to be sure it won't suddenly spoof later ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://mywebsite/filexx/yyyyy/abaete/374/?p=1';

$explodedUrl = explode('/',$url);
$countArray = count($explodedUrl);
if(strpos($explodedUrl[$countArray-1],'?') === FALSE){
    $yourId = $explodedUrl[$countArray-1];
} else {
    $yourId = $explodedUrl[$countArray-2];
}
```

`$yourId` contains your Id

Comment: Fine but if there the url is like this?  $url = http://mywebsite/filexx/yyyyy/abaete/374 ?

Comment: What if the GET values behind the URL grow long and get more complex and maybe even container new (escaped) slashes?

Answer (score 0):

```
http://mywebsite/filexx/yyyyy/abaete/374    

$url2 = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if(preg_match('~([0-9]+)\/\?p=~', $url2, $matches))
{
    $meuid = $matches[1];
}
```

This gets the numbers before /?p=.

Comment: this get before P but i have 2 situation without /?p and with /?p i can 2 two diferent functions to each situations, i m try one solution to work for both cases.

Comment: I suggest adding an identifier before the ID or it can get confusing. You could do something like "http://mywebsite/filexx/yyyyy/abaete/meuid-374/?p=1".